# weighted HITS algorithm implementatoion (hub and authority score)

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, search-engine, information-retrieval

I'm working on weighted version of HITS algorithm implementation.

This is the formula for Hits algorithm (non weighted version):
[image]

where HITS A is the authority score and HITS H is the hub score, pseudo code of the algorithm in wikipedia:

```
 G := set of pages
 for each page p in G do
   p.auth = 1 // p.auth is the authority score of the page p
   p.hub = 1 // p.hub is the hub score of the page p
 function HubsAndAuthorities(G)

   for step from 1 to k do // run the algorithm for k steps
     norm = 0
     for each page p in G do  // update all authority values first
       p.auth = 0
       for each page q in p.incomingNeighbors do // p.incomingNeighbors is the set of pages that link to p
          p.auth += q.hub
       norm += square(p.auth) // calculate the sum of the squared auth values to normalise
     norm = sqrt(norm)
     for each page p in G do  // update the auth scores 
       p.auth = p.auth / norm  // normalise the auth values
     norm = 0
     for each page p in G do  // then update all hub values
      p.hub = 0
       for each page r in p.outgoingNeighbors do // p.outgoingNeighbors is the set of pages that p links to
         p.hub += r.auth
       norm += square(p.hub) // calculate the sum of the squared hub values to normalise
     norm = sqrt(norm)
     for each page p in G do  // then update all hub values
       p.hub = p.hub / norm   // normalise the hub values
```

How can I change this algorithm to work for weighted version of the problem:
[image]

Please provide the Pseudocode or the java implementation

Comment: Can you be more specific about what problem you're having in implementing the algorithm?

Comment: I can't figure out how to modify the original algorithm to the weighted model. where am I supposed to multiply the weight of the edge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a weighted version of the algorithm, you need to change the code in the updating part:

```
p.hub += weight(p,r) * r.auth
           ^^^
```

And similarly:

```
p.auth += weight(q,p) * q.hub
            ^^^
```

Note that this update decays to the original algorithm if we set `wight(u,v)=1` for all nodes, which is a desired property.